# JSF Multiple users cause ViewExpiredException

Tags: session, jsf, primefaces

I have built a simple login system for my JSF/Primefaces site using a sessionMap. In my main view, ParliamentManager which is a SessionScoped bean I have:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void postInit() {
      logger.log(Level.INFO,"Session started");
      ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
      Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();

      user = (User) sessionMap.get("user");
      logger.log(Level.INFO, "user trader is: {0}", 
              new Object[]{user.getTrader().getTraderId().toString()});
      userId = user.getUserId();
```

In my login view which is a RequestScoped ManagedBean I have:

```
public void login(ActionEvent event) {
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    boolean loggedIn = false;

    User user = request.findUser(username);
    if(user.getPassword().equals(this.getPassword()))
    {
        loggedIn = true;
        context.getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
         logger.log(Level.INFO, "put user {0}", 
              new Object[]{user.getUserId()});
         logger.log(Level.INFO, "session id {0}", 
                  new Object[]{context.getExternalContext().getSessionId(false)});
        requestContext.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    }
}
```

In my login page I simply redirect to the main index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
    if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {
        PF('dlg').jq.effect("shake", {times:5}, 100);
    }
    else {
        PF('dlg').hide();
        $('#loginLink').fadeOut();
        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/mysite/index.xhtml"
    }
}
```

This works ok if I have two users logged in (one in a browser session, another in an incognito session). However if I add a third user (another invognito session) I get a ViewExpiredException when submitting my ajax request within a form. I thought that I could have a large amount of sessions as I'd expect many users so I'm not clear on why I get the exception in these cirumstances. Am I associating the user and session incorrectly or could there be some other issue causing the exception?

Thanks,
Zobbo

Comment: Are those two different "incognito" like one in chrome or one in firefox? Or both in the same browser incognito browser ?

Comment: Hi Jorge. They're all in  the same browser (Chrome). So one "normal" tab, a new incognito window and another incognito window. Thanks.

Comment: Chrome shares sessions across incognito instances, unfortunately. Use Firefox to do this.

Comment: People have answered you both in comments and in a answer.

Comment: Thanks Jorge and Ingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome all incognito sessions share the same cookie jar. It's only destroyed once all incognito sessions are closed. This means that a second incognito session shares the cookies with the other incognito sessions. See [1].

You can either use a session in another browser or use a browser like Firefox with multiple private sessions as Firefox doesn't share cookies like that.

[1] https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24690